# Where can I get a Running Object Table Viewer like IROTVIEW?

Tags: com, ole, running-object-table

Once upon a time Windows SDK (or it was Visual Studio) had a tool named IROTVIEW which enumerated the [Running Object Table (ROT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Where can I get this tool now?

Comment: Try this SO Q & A... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619838/anyone-got-c-sharp-source-for-running-object-table-viewer/38619839#38619839

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This site](http://alax.info/blog/1444) has a pretty good viewer for download in 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

[This site](https://gist.github.com/Grynn/1475780) has a simple enumeration class, but it needs some improvement since if you have two objects running with the same name (like two instances of Excel), it cannot populate the dictionary with the duplicate key.